# Linux Page Replacement Algorithms vs Page Frame Reclaiming Algorithms

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am learning for a Operating Systems CS exam.
In the Memory managament chapter, we have covered Page Replacement Algorithms.
In the same chapter we dove into Memory Management in Linux.

In the Memory Management of Linux, we covered something called Page Frame Reclaiming.

Now as far as I understand, Page Replacement Algorithms are used every time a page fault occured i.e. the operating system trying to fetch some data from main memory that is not there and then fetching the referenced data from secondary memory.
And it then chooses some page to replace in the page table that is contained in main memory, the "victim" page will that be written to a page file on secondy memory.

First of all is this "view" correct?

My understanding of Page Frame Reclaiming from what I've learned during class is: Page Frame Reclaiming basically keep some free pages in memory at any time, such that when a page fault occurs we can just use some free page that has been kept free by Page Frame Reclaiming. And thus there is no need for determining a page to be evicted, since we just use the free one.

And it keeps these number of free pages above a certain threshold, by periodic reclaiming.

Second is this "view" also correct?

Last question :)
Why do we need Page Frame Reclaiming, wouldn't it be better to actually use those pages that are beeing kept free by Page Frame Reclaiming, and thus reducing page faults. Why is there a need for both Page Replacement algorithms and Page Frame Reclaiming?

I really appreciate any help :D.

Comment: If the page being replaced is dirty, we can't reuse it until we write it to disk. Page reclaiming ensures that there are always clean pages available for reuse.

Comment: @Barmar, and thus keeping the operating sytem more repsonsive, since we don't have to write the previous page to disk first?

Comment: Right. We can put dirty pages on a queue to be written when convenient.

Comment: @Barmar Alright, thank you very much for helping and taking the time to answer :).